# C++ class question

Tags: c++, class

I am reviewing for my final, and I cannot figure out why this question is what it is.

Assume the following class declaration:

```
class Testing {
 public:
       Testing(int n);
       void Show(const Testing& w, int a = 10);
       int value;
 private:
       int DoThis();
 };
```

Assume the following lines of code are attempting in a main() program, and that x is of type `Testing` and has been propertly created.

`x.Show(18);` Legal or Illegal

The answer is legal, I understand that the 2nd parameter is not needed because of the `= 10`,but since `18` is not of type `Testing` isn't that an invalid parameter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Testing has a non-`explicit` constructor that takes an int. Therefore, an int can be implicitely converted to a `Testing` by constructing a temporary object.

Since Show takes a `const Testing &` (and not just a `Testing &`), you can pass a temporary to it. Finally, the second parameter is optional, so you don't have to specify a value for that.

This whole mechanism is what allows you do this, by the way:

```
void f(const std::string &str);
// ...
f("Hello");
```

Here, `"Hello"` is of type `const char (&)[6]`, which decays to a `const char *`, but you can construct a `std::string` from a `const char *`, thus permitting the use of a `const char *` where a `std::string` parameter is needed.

Keep in mind that this constructs a temporary, and therefore is only valid for parameters that are passed by value or by const reference (it will fail for references). Also, the constructor must not be marked as `explicit`.

Comment: Thanks, there were a few good answers, but this is very thorough. Thanks for taking the time to give me an explanation.

Comment: The type of `"Hello"` is `const char(&)[6]`, which decays to a `const char*`.

Answer (score 6):

There is a notion of automatic conversions in C++, called [implicit conversion sequences](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/implicit_conversion_sequences.htm). At most one conversion in such a sequence may be a user defined one, and calling a constructor for a temporary object is a user-defined conversion. It's ok to create a temporary here as that will be bound to the const-reference, and destroyed when the Show() call is complete.

Answer (score 5):

Because `Testing` has a constructor that accepts an `int`, that c-tor is used to automatically construct a `Testing` object for the first parameter. The code actually ends up working something like:

```
x.Show(Testing(18));
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor here:

```
Testing(int n);
```

provides an implicit conversion from `int` to `Testing`, and this then matches the prototype for `Show`, with the first parameter being a `Testing` instance constructed from the `int` 18, and the second parameter being the default value 10.

If you prevent implicit conversion like this:

```
explicit Testing(int n);
```

the code will not compile.